# How do I list specific words it finds in the order it finds them in

Tags: python

I'm creating a discord bot and was wondering how I could list out the words in order it finds them in?

```py
item_dict = {
    "okay": ("Mythical", "50000"),
    "hello": ("Mythical", "17500"),
    "hi": ("Legendary", "14500"),
    "good": ("Legendary", "11600"),
    "very bad": ("Common", "1"),
    }

msg = input("Enter ")
new_list = []

for x in item_dict:
    if x in msg:
        new_list.append(x)
        
print(new_list)
```

If for example I enter `4 hi 3 very bad good`, I would want it to check the string and check if it matches any of the items in the dictionary and make it print `[hi, very bad, good]` instead of how its ordered in the dictionary which would print out `[hi, good, very bad]`.

Comment: So do you want the items be sorted based on their value in the dictionary?

Comment: @XxJames07-I want the items to be sorted the way the user enters an input. So entering very bad, hello, hi would be stay the same, instead of it being hello, hi, very bad

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the dictionary loop through the message and then you can look for word matches when you hit a letter that matches the start of a key, like so:

```
item_dict = {
  "okay": ("Mythical", "50000"),
  "hello": ("Mythical", "17500"),
  "hi": ("Legendary", "14500"),
  "good": ("Legendary", "11600"),
  "very bad": ("Common", "1"),
}

msg = input("Enter ")
new_list = []

for index, letter in enumerate(msg):
  for key in item_dict.keys():
    if letter == key[0]:
      if msg[index:index+len(key)] == key:
        new_list.append(key)
        break



print(new_list)
```

This solution can also handle spaces in the dictionary keys, albeit at a higher computation cost.

Comment: This works. Can you explain `if msg[index:index+len(key)] == key` this piece of code please. I feel like I'm confusing myself the more I look at it

Comment: Yeah, no problem, lets take the example of the memory being in this state:
key='hello'
msg='tomato hello good'

So we can convert the msg[index:index+len(key)] to their values in memory:
'tomato hello good'[7:7+5] 
This equates to:
'hello'

So we are looking at the current position we are at in the string and looking the length of the key ahead to see if that matches the key.

Hopefully that explains it well, I do think the other answer using the lamdba is a better solution since it's less confusing.

Comment: Ohh I see. So does the `if letter == key[0]` check if the letter matches the first letter of the key in the dictionary, which in this case is `h`? 

Also, I would use the other answer, but I'm yet to still learn lambda. I still get confused at the way its used

Comment: Yeah, ```if letter == key[0]``` does check if the letter matches the first letter. I did compare the speed of my solution to the other solution and mine was over 10 times faster.

Other solution in miliseconds
8.106231689453125e-06
My solution in miliseconds
1.9073486328125e-05

This speed difference is unlikely going to matter unless you are dealing with a huge dictionary/message. In most situations I would say straight forward code trumps speed optimization.

Comment: @RyanNygard clearly you do not know how time measurements work....

Comment: @RyanNygard your solution is slower if those are the values you got, lol. why do you think 0.00001 is faster than 0.000008?

Comment: @Ryan, you are right, I misread it.

Answer (score 1):

Sort `new_list` with a `lambda`, with the `key` being the position the word is found in `msg`.

Code:

```
item_dict = {
    "okay": ("Mythical", "50000"),
    "hello": ("Mythical", "17500"),
    "hi": ("Legendary", "14500"),
    "good": ("Legendary", "11600"),
    "very bad": ("Common", "1"),
    }

msg = input("Enter ")
new_list = []

for x in item_dict:
    if x in msg:
        new_list.append(x)
        
new_list.sort(key=lambda x: msg.find(x))
        
        
print(new_list)
```

Output:

Enter

```
4 hi 3 very bad good
['hi', 'very bad', 'good']
```

Comment: This doesn't work on multiple words

Comment: I changed the names of the values inside the dictionaries. There's basically a lot of values we call items for users to use and a lot of them will have spaces

Comment: @Hahaha2411 I will update my answer to make it work for spaces

Comment: @Hahaha2411 I have updated my answer. It now works for the cases you specified.

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to explain the lambda part in this?

Comment: @Hahaha2411 lambda is an in-place function. In this case, it takes the parameter `x`, which can be thought of as each element of new_list. The `key` is what tells the list how to sort itself, so in this case, the elements are sorted according to where they are found -- `msg.find(x)`.